# How is $a^x$ defined (without using Logarithm) for $a<0$?

Tags: exponential-function

let  $a\in \mathbb{R},x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ .

now : how is defined $a^x$ ?(without using Logarithm)

---

i know that : if : $a>1$ then:
$$a^x:=\sup\{a^r:r\in \mathbb{Q},r<x\}=\inf\{a^r:r\in \mathbb{Q},r>x\}$$

and if $b\in(0,1)$. then $\dfrac{1}{b}>1$ and  :

$$b^x:=(\dfrac{1}{b})^{-x}$$.

---

### my question :

Can be defined $a^x$ such that : $a<0 \in \mathbb{R} ,x$ be Irrational number
.

Comment: (+1) Interesting and seems to work. Maybe you should add that $a<0$ in the title.

Comment: **No**, if $a<0$ then $a^x$ is not defined among the reals. As a *complex* number, it can take though infinitely many (but nonreal) values, all having absolute value $|a|^x$ and angles $(2k+1)\pi\cdot x$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Why is it only defined for odd numbers?

Comment: Don't need the two definitions for a>1, b < 1.  Just do a^x = lim q->x a^q.  Doesn't matter if a <,=,or > 1.  Can not define for a < 0 because limits don't exist.

Comment: @fleablood But that means you expect the limit to exist, which is a too strong assumption for the generalization!

Comment: What?  Of course, I don't expect the limit to exist!  That's exactly *why* it can't be defined for irrational $x$.